# What does the google search homepage ( https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl ) lack in design?

Tags: website-design, homepage, google

Google has kept its homepage clean with minimum possible buttons, but what still this homepage lacks from design point of view? Or what else could be added to it or removed to make it a better design?

Comment: The current look of Google's homepage is based on more than 10 years of rigorous testing. Why do you think it lacks something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is - nothing. Google has invested months and years of their time and money into researching their ux. Their home page contains exactly what their user needs.